# Using IntBuffer for BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

As the title aleady says, it want to create a BufferedImage that is backed by a specific (already existing) IntBuffer.

Up to this point, I have the following code:

```
final IntBuffer buf = ...;
DataBuffer dbuf = new DataBuffer(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT,size) {
    public void setElem(int bank, int i, int val) {
        buf.put(i,val);
    }
    public int getElem(int bank, int i) {
        return buf.get(i);
    }
};
ColorModel cm = ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(dim.width,dim.height);
WritableRaster raster = WritableRaster.createWritableRaster(sm,dbuf,null);
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cm,raster,false,new Hashtable<>());
```

This code however shows the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: IntegerComponentRasters must haveinteger DataBuffers
at sun.awt.image.IntegerComponentRaster.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:100)
```

(The line is the one where the WritableRaster is created.)
It is very important to me that the data doesn´t have to be copied, because I´ll use BufferedImage mainly as a comfortable interface to write to the underlying IntBuffer (with some few exceptions).

Comment: Did you copy this from some other forum? Don't put `<br>` tags after each line. SO has its own format.

Comment: I've tried to fix your post's formatting, but please read any site's editing recommendations before posting. Thanks for your cooperation in the future on this.

Comment: I tried to format this correctly, but my English is not the best. So the help-files on this topic confused me. However, thanks for formatting it. And of course I did NOT copy this from anywhere but programmed it myself by trial-and-error. (In times where breaking Copyright-law can cost thousands of euros, it´s probably not a good idea to copy&paste.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, trying to create a `DataBuffer` backed by a nio `ByteBuffer`. What you are trying to do is possible, but not using the `Raster.createWritableRaster` methods (I think it's a bug, but it's been like that for ages, so don't expect it to be fixed any time soon). You need to directly create an instance of a writable raster.

Either:

```
WritableRaster = new sun.awt.image.SunWritableRaster(...);
```

Or, create your own subclass of `WritableRaster` (it's trivial, you don't actually need to override any methods, except maybe `toString` to aid debugging).

```
class GenericWritableRaster extends WritableRaster {
    public GenericWritableRaster(SampleModel model, DataBuffer buffer, Point origin) {
        super(model, buffer, origin);
    }
}

WritableRaster = new GenericWritableRaster(...);
```

For some inspiration, you can have a look at my [GenericWritableRaster](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/GenericWritableRaster.java) implementation, and
the [MappedImageFactory](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) class for how to use it.

The resulting images will always be of type `BufferedImage.TYPE_CUSTOM` (and thus probably slow from Java), but this is probably no problem for you if you have a library that already holds the images in the graphics card's RAM.

---

Update, here's an SSCCE PoC based on your code:

```
public class BufferTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(100, 100);
        int size = dim.width * dim.height;

        final IntBuffer buf = IntBuffer.wrap(new int[size]);

        DataBuffer dbuf = new DataBuffer(DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, size) {
            public void setElem(int bank, int i, int val) {
                buf.put(i, val);
            }

            public int getElem(int bank, int i) {
                return buf.get(i);
            }
        };
        ColorModel cm = ColorModel.getRGBdefault();
        SampleModel sm = cm.createCompatibleSampleModel(dim.width, dim.height);
        WritableRaster raster = new WritableRaster(sm, dbuf, new Point()) {};
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cm, raster, false, null);

        System.err.println("img: " + img);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
img: BufferedImage@234441b6: type = 0 DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=ff000000 com.twelvemonkeys.image.BufferTest$2@563625d0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the bytecode of `IntegerComponentRaster`, which throws your exception, and it explicitly checks whether the `DataBuffer` instance you pass in is a subclass of `DataBufferInt`.
Unfortunately, you cannot easily extend this class, as it's declared `final`. So I'm afraid you can't do what you need.

As an alternative, maybe you can create the `DataBuffer` first, and then wrap its contents in a `IntBuffer`? Something like this:

```
DataBufferInt dbuf = new DataBufferInt(size);
IntBuffer buf = IntBuffer.wrap(dbuf.getData());
// Fill the IntBuffer etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for analyzing IntegerComponentRaster. That´s very bad news for me, because it´s important that the data is allocated in the IntBuffer, not in the DataBuffer. I don´t have direct access to the raw data (int[]), because it´s stored directly in the graphics-card most of the time and is handled by a third-party library. Write and read to this data is only possible by using the methods provided by IntBuffer.